# text2wav MIME type error wasm compile issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use the text2wav.js node module to convert a string into an audio file. Whenever I try to run the function in the example I get the error:

backend.js:6 wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

I am using this code inside of a component inside a react application

I am not sure where to Begin as I am not familiar with wasm types or how WebAssembly compiles them

```
recognize = async () => { //bound to my react class called Body

         (async () => {
 const text2wav = require('text2wav')
 let out = await text2wav('test')
 // out is of type Uint8Array
 const assert = require('assert')
 assert.equal(out[0], 82) //R
 assert.equal(out[1], 73) //I
 assert.equal(out[2], 70) //F
 assert.equal(out[3], 70) //F
})()


     };
```

I am getting this error:

wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By text2wav I assume you mean [text2wav.node.js](https://github.com/abbr/text2wav.node.js). As the full name suggested, the module only works on node.js. React application runs on browser rather than on node.js, therefore it won't work.